# UTF Caracteres en un REGEX y Preg_Match

Tags: regex, utf-8, preg-match

Hola Tengo este String

```
"url":"https:\u002F\u002Fquisqueya.video/us9xrgoi.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOifk",
```

Estoy Usando este Preg_Mach

```
$link_pre=curl_get_data ($id);
$re = '/(quisqueya.video[^\s"]+)/';
preg_match($re, $link_pre, $link);
```

Y con el consigo este resultado

```
quisqueya.video/us9xrgoi.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOifk
```

Pero necesito ser mas presiso, pero como no se manejar los caracteres UTF a la hora de crear el Regex no me arroja nada

```
/"url":"http|s:\u002F\u002F(quisqueya.video[^\s"].m3u|8+)",/
```

estoy necesitando este resultado:

```
https://quisqueya.video/us9xrgoi.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOifk
```

Grx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo lo que intentaste, podría ser:

```
~"url":"https?://(quisqueya\.video/[^\s"?]+\.m3u8)[^\s"]+"~
```

Los `|` tienen la más baja precedencia, por eso funcionaban como un gran `or` que dividía completamente a tu regex.

Comment: Pase tu REGEX a traves de un probador y siguen molestando los \u002F mira el caso aqui. https://pythex.org/?regex=%22url%22%3A%22https%3F%3A%2F%2F(quisqueya%5C.video%2F%5B%5E%5Cs%22%3F%5D%2B%5C.m3u8)%5B%5E%5Cs%22%5D%2B%22&test_string=%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%5Cu002F%5Cu002Fquisqueya.video%2Fus9xrgoi.m3u8%3Ftoken%3DeyJhbGciOifk%22%2C&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: @Torronf si `\u002F` está como literal en vez del caracter `/`, debería ir así tal cual en el regex: `~"url":"https?:\\\\u002F\\\\u002F(quisqueya\.video/[^\s"?]+\.m3u8)[^\s"]+"~`... Probá el código en PHP, no en pythex.org que es para Python: https://rextester.com/FXXC72886